# Переход по ссылке под определенным UserAgent | Защита от воров

Tags: php, html, xnet

Интересует как сделать так, что-бы авторизация на мой сайт происходила для определенного UserAgent-а, а для остальных - блокировалась.

В чем смысл. У меня есть сайт, на нем лежит txt файл. При обращении к сайту по типу link ru/ex.txt у меня открывается мой текстовик(очевидно).
Эта ссылка используется в моем софте. А софт подписочный(продается по подписке)

При сниффе приложения - ссылка вылавливается и без проблем можно узнать что там. Мне нужно сделать так, что-бы исключительно мой софт мог отправлять запрос. Очень буду благодарен за любые идеи и помощь.

Comment: Не стоит так делать. 1) Запрос легко перехватить, 2) UserAgent - легко подменить. Для усложнения жизни взломщикам - используйте RSA =)

Comment: Можно попробовать это сделать с помощью правил в .htaccess.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864727/htaccess-allow-all-from-specific-user-agent

Comment: Это просто: если софт ваш - он должен отправлять HTTP заголовки в одном заголовке указать id пользователя, во втором уникальный ключ в md5, где до md5 это будет алгоритм по смешиванию уникального ключа, хранящегося у вас в базе и у него в программе и текущего года. Если кто то из пользователей поставит себе чужой ключ - при расшифровке ключа будет несостыковка с вашей базой данных, а также если нет этих заголовков то тоже ничего не получат

Comment: можно не обязательно года, а уникального номера устройства, на котором сидит пользователь - например просить его по емеил подтвердить что его устройство это действительно его, тогда добавить это устройство в в список устройств пользователя